# Error opening audio device (null) for capture: Connection refused FATAL: "continuous.c", line 245: Failed to open audio device

Tags: ubuntu, pulseaudio, error-handling

I am trying to install pocketsphinx on my ARM-based board(nanopi-m1), and use Ubuntu-Core 16.04 on it. But when I try to test pocketsphinx with this command:

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes
```

I get this error message:

```
Error opening audio device (null) for capture: Connection refused
FATAL: "continuous.c", line 245: Failed to open audio device
```

I have instaleed `pulseaudio` and `libpulse-dev` before installing pocketsphinx, but I get the error message!

Comment: Guess: pulseaudio not running, or running as a different user. Can you use `paplay` or `parec`? (see man-pages for options).

Comment: @dirkt: no they don't work!

Comment: For paplay: `Failed to open audio file.`
For parec: `Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused‍‍`

Comment: Also I tried `getent group audio` and found `audio:x:29:pulse`

Comment: So the problem isn't `pocketsphinx`. Does `ps axu | grep pulse` show that the demon is running? If not, can you start it with `pulseaudio --start`?

Comment: @dirkt:  `ps axu | grep pulse`:

`root       908  0.0  0.0   4116   548 pts/0    S+   06:35   0:00 grep --color=auto pulse`
And for:
`pulseaudio --start`:

`W: [pulseaudio] main.c: This program is not intended to be run as root (unless --system is specified).`

Comment: I should mention I use SSH mode to using my board(the board is connected to my router by LAN cable and I use my laptop that is connected by Wi-Fi to that router too)

Comment: I don't know how but the problem solved!

Comment: I don't know how you solved the problem, but in general: Login as a user, not as root, to use Pulseaudio and programs like pocketsphinx. Root should only do system-related tasks.